# On a statement in The Joy of Factoring By Samuel S. Wagstaff (Jr.)?

Tags: algorithms, quadratics, factoring, quadratic-forms, prime-factorization

In 'The Joy of Factoring By Samuel S. Wagstaff (Jr.)' on page $32$ it is mentioned that Euler, Legendre, Gauss, and Chebyshev have observed that in $$ax^2+bxy+cy^2=N$$ for two different $(x,y)$ pairs then we can factor $N$. What is the correct procedure for this?

Comment: There's a full paper on the procedure of solving these equations [here](http://www.jpr2718.org/mtthbin.pdf).

Comment: Here is an understandable note on $m a^2 + n b^2 = N $  http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Brillhart_Euler_factoring_2009.pdf

Comment: @WillJagy Does $ax^2+bxy+cy^2$ reduce to $mu^2+nv^2$ form?

Comment: @Robut not over the integers; the positive $m a^2 + n b^2 = N$ should be easier to follow than the general case.

Comment: @WillJagy but the general case could be more useful. is there insight on that?